# The bytePerRow value is strange while creating an iOS Metal texture

Tags: ios, swift, graphics, metal

I am drawing a YUV420 image using Metal.
The problem is that when creating a 1080x1920 image texture, the Y, U, and V plane bytePerRow values ​​are generated as 1088, 544, and 544.
My opinion should be generated as 1080, 540, 540.

Due to the above problem, the image is generated strangely.
Is there any way to solve this problem?

[image]

```
var pixelBuffer : CVPixelBuffer?

CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, width, height, kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8Planar, pixelAttributes as CFDictionary?, &pixelBuffer)
// width = 1080, height = 1920

CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRowOfPlane(pixelBuffer,0) // return val -> 1088
CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRowOfPlane(pixelBuffer,1) // return val -> 544
CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRowOfPlane(pixelBuffer,2) // return val -> 544
```

Comment: It's possibly a hardware "stride" issue. 1080 is not divisible by 16 or 32, but 1088 is, and having raster lines start on multiples of 16 or 32-bytes _may_ be a HW requirement.

Comment: Does that mean can't create a texture with a width of 1080?

Comment: How are you creating your texture? The various APIs that enable you to get data into an `MTLTexture` (whether `replaceRegion(_:...)`, `MTLBlitCommandEncoder`, or `CVMetalTextureCache`) should all allow you to specify (or tacitly respect) the row stride of the source buffer.

Comment: What I want is that each plane bytesPerRow of CVPixelBuffer is created with 1080, 540, 540.
Either way, the bytePerRow of each plane will not be set to the desired value.

Comment: @SKWyverns29 RE _"Does that mean can't create a texture with a width of 1080?"_  You can probably create a texture with a *logical* width of 1080 but it might have to be *stored* in a physical layout that is 1088 wide.

Comment: May I suggest taking a look at a working example of this sort of thing? https://github.com/mdejong/MetalBT709Decoder